# How to determine if the user had clicked on a UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, ios

I need to get the url that a `UIWebView` is displaying after the user clicks on it once.

I've tried putting a button which calls a method which determines the url, under the `UIWebView`, but this way the button doesn't work. I've tried putting a button over a `UIWebView` but this way it gives not the url after the click, but the starting url.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By clicking the UIWebView do you mean clicking a link on the webpage it self or literally clicking anywhere on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to know if somebody has clicked over your view is implementing touchesEnded method:
First declare a rect with the size of your webView in your viewDidLoad for example:

```
touchRect=CGRectMake(YourWebView.startPositionX, YourWebView.StartPositionY,YourWebView.width, YourWebView.height);
```

and then implement the touchesEnded:

```
(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(touch){

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(touchRect,  location)){

            //do whatever

        }
    }

}
```

This way you will know if you have make a touch inside your webView.

Comment: I guess you have an UIViewController where you are adding your webView have you? you have to put his code in your UIviewController class

Answer (score 1):

To display the current location of UIWebView (location of main page):

```
NSURLRequest* webViewRequest = [myWebView request];
if (webViewRequest) {
    NSURL* webViewURL = [webViewRequest URL];
    NSString* webViewLocation = [webViewURL absoluteString];
}
```